# Batch versus Future ? which way should we prefer in below requirement?

Tags: asynchronous

We have 100 account records ,we need to send the each of account record to make call-out. Which would be preferable and why ?

If future is not preferable and why ?

We can do call outs making batch and future, which would be preferable in which scenario?

Could anyone please explain with example ?

Comment: is your API bulkified ? meaning can you send all 100 accounts in one callout ?

Comment: No, that callout accepts only one Id at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple downsides to using future methods.

1. You can only invoke 50 future in a single transaction.So even if you use future method, you have to make call out per records in for loop which is going to take too much time and break your transaction
2. A single Apex transaction can make a maximum of 100 callouts to an HTTP request. So if the number of records changes over time, in that case , this solution is not scalable.

On the other hand, you wont face all this issues if you have a batch.I suggest you go with batch or you ask you provider to make the API bulkified. In that case, you can make a callout from future method.

Comment: Is that 10 future calls per transaction or 50 future calls per transaction?

Comment: You can make 50 future calls per transaction. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my answer. And Yes, you can pass the list of Id to future method. If you want  to pass the full object, you can serialize your Sobject to JSON and pass as string to future and then  deserialize the string back to SObject in Future methods

Comment: @future(callout=true) 
 global static void callABPSer(List<Id> actIds>
 { for (Id eachId : actIds) 
  {webservicecall.method(actId)}
 }
so in above we are making 100 callouts per this transction correct and 1 future call
// and dont we need to wait for first call completes, again we can make remaining 99 callouts because of future ?
//If we use Batch
global static execute(database.batchablecontext bc, List<Account> acts){
 for(Account act : acts){
        webservicecall.method(act.Id); }
}// so in above do we need to wait for the second callout ??

Comment: if you will not wait for the response, how will you log the response and find which records were sent and which were not? And what if number of records changed over time? then this approach will fail. In ideal scenario, everyone will suggest batch.Rest is up to you and decide which mechanism to use.

Comment: You do not need to use a loop in batch. Make a callout only for one records in execute method and run the batch with a scope of 1. This will call the execute method with only one records and make a callout or Total number of callouts (HTTP requests or Web services calls) is 100, that means if you have one callout in your execute method you can keep batch size as 100.

Comment: Thanks for the help Samir, from your answers I came to know that batch is preferable  over Future. As the number of records increases, future method may hit governor limit of 100 callouts, so it would be better to go for Batch correct ?

Comment: yes. Batch is preferable for your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you should be using Queueable. Batchble has quite a bit of overhead (a minimum of 3 asynchronous calls to handle just one record), and also doesn't scale well if you need to use it in triggers (due to the 100 batch limit in the Flex Queue).

Future methods can't be chained, so you need to make sure that you call it enough times so that the individual future methods won't fail, while still staying under the 50 future call per transaction limit.

Queueable, on the other hand, is like Batchable, can leverage the new finializer interface to recover from governor limit errors, and can be chained as many, or as few, times as possible.

Batch processes are really mean to handle situations where you need to process thousands of records infrequently, and future methods are generally not as good as Queueable, as they're quite limited in functionality compared to Queueable.

Comment: Thanks for you reply sfdcfox!!!. But I really did not get your answer ... Could you please elaborate